# SVG override my background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, background-image

I was wondering how I can use SVG "on" a background?  Not to use SVG "as" a background.

I have my div with css code with background color. but when I import SVG, the  background it turns white. Does SVG override the background colors?

Is there any way I can import it without affecting the background but keeping the SVG shape?

```
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #EAFEFF, #DFF3FF);
background: -moz-linear-gradient( #EAFEFF, #DFF3FF);
border: 1px solid #000;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-image: url(SVG/revenue_icon.svg), none;
background-size: 100%;
width: 92%;
height: 92%;
margin: 1px 1px;
```

SVG:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 150 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#05415B;} 
</style>
<g id="XMLID_94_">
    <path id="XMLID_122_" class="st0" d="M102.1,32.7H47.9c-4,0-7.2,3.2-7.2,7.2v70.1c0,4,3.2,7.2,7.2,7.2h54.2c4,0,7.2-3.2,7.2-7.2
        V39.9C109.3,36,106.1,32.7,102.1,32.7z M75.1,101.1L61.5,76.2l7.7-0.2V48.9h12.7v26.9l8-0.2L75.1,101.1z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: My guess is that there is something in your SVG adding the white background, like the `fill` attribute, `fill="#FFFFFF"`.

Comment: Is this removable, or is it just a bad SVG file that I ve made?
Because if Im not mistaken SVGs are lines. so they should have any background

Comment: it seems there is a fill. but if I change it to none it still has the same background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(background)Gradients in css are treated as background-image ( [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) ) so you are overriding the gradient here, background-image: url(SVG/revenue_icon.svg), none;

You could do something like this:

```
.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(SVG/revenue_icon.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It works. Now that you mentioned it, I just noticed that on my rush I was overriding the background in the same class with the SVG. Novice mistake.